# UCanAccess Java Execution Error

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

When attempting to get details from an MS Access database using the following code:

```
//returns the details of a specific employee for use in the update GUI
public static String getEmployeeDetails(int empID) throws SQLException{
    String employee = "";
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT employeetbl.Department, "
            + "employeetbl.Surname, "
            + "employeetbl.FirstName, "
            + "employeetbl.CurrentPosition, "
            + "FORMAT(employeetbl.DateOfBirth, 'yyyy/mm/dd') AS DateOfBirth, "
            + "employeetbl.TotalYearsRelevantExperience, "
            + "employeetbl.HighestQualification, "
            + "employeetbl.EmailAddress, "
            + "employeetbl.PhoneNo, "
            + "FORMAT(employeetbl.DateOfEmployment, 'yyyy/mm/dd') AS DateOfEmployment "
            + "FROM employeetbl WHERE EmployeeID = "+empID+";";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
        employee = rs.getString("Department")
                +"#"+rs.getString("Surname")
                +"#"+rs.getString("FirstName")
                +"#"+rs.getString("CurrentPosition")
                +"#"+rs.getString("DateOfBirth")
                +"#"+rs.getString("TotalYearsRelevantExperience")
                +"#"+rs.getString("HighestQualification")
                +"#"+rs.getString("EmailAddress")
                +"#"+rs.getString("PhoneNo")
                +"#"+rs.getString("DateOfEmployment");
    }
    return employee;
}
```

called from this method:

```
if(cmbTable.getSelectedItem().equals("Employees")){
            String[] tmp = cmbRecord.getSelectedItem().toString().split("-");
            int empID = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
            String employeeDetails = Master.getEmployeeDetails(empID);
            String[] employee = employeeDetails.split("#");
            cmbDepartment.setSelectedItem(employee[0]);
            txtSurname.setText(employee[1]);
            txtFirstName.setText(employee[2]);
            txtCurrentPos.setText(employee[3]);
            txtDOB.setText(employee[4]);
            txtExperience.setText(employee[5]);
            txtQualification.setText(employee[6]);
            txtEmail.setText(employee[7]);
            txtPhone.setText(employee[8]);
            txtEmployment.setText(employee[9]);
        }
```

I am met with the following error

```
error: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.0 Java execution: FORMAT
```

I have no idea what is causing this error since the SQL works perfectly fine when executed in Access and the format is needed otherwise it outputs the records information including the time which is not set or used.

Comment: Did you look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191830/java-error-net-ucanaccess-jdbc-ucanaccesssqlexception-malformed-string

Comment: no but it isn't relevant to my question as the error is different. and all the suggestions made there I have already implemented to no avail.

Comment: OK, I thought it might be useful. I suspected that it might be your setup: wrong jdbc driver, wrong connection string, etc... Especially since you said the SQL works with MS Access. I'd google for a tutorial on accessing MS Access with JDBC to see if you can figure out what's not working.

Comment: It works perfectly as soon as I do not use the FORMAT function however it then gives me the date in the wrong format and i am unable to use it properly for my program

Comment: Guess its a problem with the `"FORMAT(employeetbl.DateOfBirth, 'yyyy/mm/dd') AS DateOfBirth, "`. That function is probably not supported by JDBC. I'd remove it and format the date after word with. [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead.

Comment: ok thanks could you perhaps give an example of how i could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd remove the `FORMAT` from your SQL string and format the date in Java. I do not know what the format of the date is being returned as, but this should allow you to parse it and then input the fields in the Calendar.set() method as shown here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2015, Calendar.AUGUST, 21, 9, 27);
    final Date date = calendar.getTime();
    final String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(date);
    System.out.println("formattedDate = " + formattedDate);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help its sorted the Format error however now its giving a new error: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.0 parameter marker not allowed

Comment: Maybe you can edit your original post and put your new SQL in it. Hard to say with you seeing your code. Maybe you changed something and added an invalid `parameter` somewhere?

Comment: Never mind i had made an error in my sql and created a parameter in the wrong place its sorted now thank you very much for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

For future readers: the format function is implemented in ucanaccess and the code originally posted is correct. So the following code runs fine with ucanaccess:

```
select format(#2001-03-02#, 'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual.
```

Nevertheless there is a lack in the handling of null arguments, which likely causes the issue. So
`select format(null, 'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual;` causes an exception to be thrown.
Even if I fixed this issue, a casting of the null values to timestamp would be needed using a specific hsqldb syntax, because of the ambiguity with the function *FORMAT(varchar,varchar) and FORMAT(double,varchar)*.
So I suggest this (simplified) workaround:

```
select nvl2(employeetbl.DateOfBirth,FORMAT(employeetbl.DateOfBirth, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),null) AS DateOfBirth from ...
```

Notice that, as well as in access, mm means month (and not minutes).